# How to automate button click after component load in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I am currently attempting to initiate a search function after a component loads in Angular. Currently the function is called by a button press, but I would like to automate this.

```
<button mat-raised-button class="mat-white-button green-button" (click)="onSearch()" style="width: 184px; top: -5px;">
                <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"></i>&nbsp; Find Shoppers
            </button>
```

I am currently attempting to call the this.onSearch() function using the lifecycle hook ngAfterContentInit() however this isn't working. It appears the function call is being made on component load however is never completed.

```
     @Component({
    templateUrl: 'search.screen.html',
})

export class SearchScreen implements OnInit {

    _dealerId: number;
    public searching: boolean;
    public form: FormGroup;
    public noResultsFound: boolean;
    public viewChecked = false;

    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
    minDate: Date;
    maxDate: Date;

    private searchSubscription: Subscription;

    // for the mat-header table component
    displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'stage', 'currentVehicle', 'topVehicle', 'mappedDate'];
    shopperCount: number;

    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<SearchResult> = new MatTableDataSource<ActiveShopperSearchResult>();

    private paginator: MatPaginator;
    private sort: MatSort;

    @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
        this.sort = ms;
        this.setDataSourceAttributes();
    }

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
        this.paginator = mp;
        this.setDataSourceAttributes();
    }

    constructor(
        private everestApiService: EverestApiService,
        private _router: Router,
        private dialog: MatDialog,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private perms: PermissionsService,
    ) {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl(null),
            phone: new FormControl(null),
            email: new FormControl(null),
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dealerId = +this._route.snapshot.params['dealerId'];

        let startDateOffset = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 30; // 30 days offset
        let startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() - startDateOffset);
        this.startDate = new Date(startDate.toString());
        this.endDate = new Date();

        let minDateOffset = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 365;
        let minDate = new Date();
        minDate.setTime(minDate.getTime() - minDateOffset);
        // this.onSearch();

    }
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        if(this.viewChecked === false) {
        this.onSearch();
        console.log(this.viewChecked)
        this.viewChecked = true;
        console.log(this.viewChecked)


        }
    }

 onSearch() {
        console.log('searching');
        this.clearResults();
        let searchParams = '?startDate=' + this.startDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
            + '&endDate=' + this.endDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10);

        if (this.form.value.name) {
            searchParams += '&name=' + this.form.value.name;
        }

        if (this.form.value.email) {
            searchParams += '&email=' + this.form.value.email;
        }

        if (this.form.value.phone) {
            searchParams += '&phone=' + this.form.value.phone;
        }

        this.searchSubscription = this.everestApiService.searchActiveShoppers(this._dealerId, searchParams)
            .pipe(track(inProgress => this.searching = inProgress))
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ActiveShopperSearchResult>();
                this.dataSource.data = data;
                this.shopperCount = data.length;
                if (data.length === 0) {
                    this.noResultsFound = true;
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it's never completed?

Comment: Show us onSearch function

Comment: Added the onSearch() function. I know its not completed as I have a spinner while 'searching' that disappears once search is completed and either the screen is populated w/ results or a msg stating no results found. In the current state I'm only getting the spinner indefinitely.

Comment: add some console.log statements to `ngAfterContentInit`, see if it prints. add it inside if and outside, see what's printed. It's likely that `(this.viewChecked === false)` is creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

add some console.log statements to `ngAfterContentInit`, see if it prints. 
add it inside if and outside, see what's printed. 
AfterViewInit() and AfterViewChecked() hooks are called by Angular after it creates a component's child views.

Also your Component should implement `implements AfterViewChecked`:

```
 export class SearchScreen implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked  { 

       ngAfterContentInit() {
        if(this.viewChecked === false) {
        this.onSearch();
        console.log(this.viewChecked)
        this.viewChecked = true;
        console.log(this.viewChecked)
       }
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a `onSearch()` method in the `ngAfterContentInit()` you could do this.

Define template variable #buttonSearch in .html

**.html**

```
<button #buttonSearch mat-raised-button class="mat-white-button green-button" (click)="onSearch()" style="width: 184px; top: -5px;">
<i class="fa fa-search" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"></i>&nbsp; Find Shoppers
</button>
```

And dispatch that event

**.ts**

```
@ViewChild('buttonSearch') private buttonSearch : ElementRef

ngAfterContentInit() {
    if(this.viewChecked === false) {
    let event = new Event('click')

    this.buttonSearch.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event)

    console.log(this.viewChecked)
    this.viewChecked = true;
    console.log(this.viewChecked)
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting a 'cannot read nativeElement of undefined' w/ this solution.

Comment: by misspelling i added an extra space in `@ViewChild('buttonSearch ')`. I i've edit the answer. Try it again, and let me know.

Comment: Thx. However I had already accounted for the extra space and removed it. I'm still getting the same error. Could it be the wrong lifecycle hook?

Comment: Here's the link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/typescript. Now i'm receiving 'cannot read property dispatchEvent of undefined'. I took out the *ngIf from parent div.

Comment: remember to save your jsfiddle, i'm just seeing a typescript boilerplate.

Comment: i couldn't see it. sorry to make you jump, but use this one, it's design for angular applicactions. https://stackblitz.com.